# What is wrong in this program //trying to reverse an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, reverse

I am trying to create a program to reverse an array by creating a temporary array defined within a fucntion and then copying the elements of the from the end of array to the start of the temporary array.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverse(int arr[])
{
    int revarray[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       for(int j=9;j>=0;j--)
       {
          revarray[j]=arr[i]; 
       }
    for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
    {
        cout<<revarray1[k]<<" ";
    }
}

int main()
{
   int arr[10];
   cout<<"Enter the elements of array"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    reverse(arr);   
}
```

[This is the output that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki3Sl.png)

Comment: why is there a nested loop? You should explain that to your rubber duck

Comment: You have an array of ten elements, and your swap instruction runs 90 times to reverse ten elements. Do you see a problem with those numbers?

Comment: Before you write a single line of a program, you must have a plan written down on paper.  If you drew two arrays, one filled with items, and the other empty, and drew how to copy from the beginning of the filled array to the back of the empty array, you will see that you can fill the empty array in one pass through the original array -- there is no "nesting" of operations (your nested `for` loops being an example), just one single pass through the data.  Now that you have this picture of the steps, you write the program that follows those steps.

Comment: Also, you should have seen a pattern: item 0 is copied to slot 9, item 1 copied to slot 8, item 2 copied to slot 7, etc.  See the pattern?  `0 -> 9, 1 -> 8,  2 -> 7 ...`.  Do you need  nested `for` loops to realize this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these nested for loops

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   for(int j=9;j>=0;j--)
   {
      revarray[j]=arr[i]; 
   }
```

you are setting all elements of the array `revarray` with values of the array `arr` within the inner for loop in each iteration of the outer for loop. As a result after the loops all elements of the array `revarray` contain the value `arr[9]`.

In any case the function is wrong because it uses the magic number `10`. So it may not be called for arrays with other numbers of elements.

If you want to reverse an array then the function can look for example the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void reverse( int arr[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        std::swap( arr[i], arr[n - i - 1] );
    }
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;    
    int arr[N];

    std::cout << "Enter the elements of array" << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }

    reverse( arr, N );   

    for ( const auto &item : arr )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Pay attention to that there is standard algorithm `std::reverse` declared in header `<algorithm>` that can be used with arrays.

In this case to reverse an array you could write

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::reverse( std::begin( arr ), std::end( arr ) );
```